# How to plot a 3-Dimension graph with Racket

Tags: plot, graph, 3d, lisp, racket

I am using Racket and Dr. Racket. There is a great library called plot which allows you to plot graphs in 2D or 3D.

After importing the package:

```
(require plot)
```

I can plot graphs like `f(x,y) = 3 * x` with:

```
(plot3d (surface3d (lambda (x y) (* x 3)) (- 10) 10 (- 10) 10))
```

[image]

However, when I try plotting this equation:

```
f (x,y,z) = 2(x-2)^2 + (y-1)^2+(z-3)^2 - 10

(plot3d (surface3d (lambda (x y z) (+ (* 2 (expt (- x 2) 2))
                                      (expt (- y 1) 2)
                                      (expt (- z 3) 2)
                                      -10))
                                      (- 10) 10 (- 10) 10))
```

I get a big message of error which I cannot understand:

```
surface3d: contract violation
  expected: a procedure that accepts 2 non-keyword argument
  given: #<procedure:...top/graficos.rkt:14:19>
  in: the 1st argument of
      (->*
       ((-> any/c any/c Real))
       ((or/c Real #f)
        (or/c Real #f)
        (or/c Real #f)
        (or/c Real #f)
        #:alpha
        Nonnegative-Real
        #:color
        (or/c
         Integer
         Symbol
         String
         (recursive-contract g147 #:impersonator)
         (cons/c
          Real
          (cons/c Real (cons/c Real '()))))
        #:label
        (or/c #f String)
        #:line-color
        (or/c
         Integer
         Symbol
         String
         (recursive-contract g147 #:impersonator)
         (cons/c
          Real
          (cons/c Real (cons/c Real '()))))
        #:line-style
        (or/c
         Integer
         'transparent
         'solid
         'dot
         'long-dash
         'short-dash
         'dot-dash)
        #:line-width
        Nonnegative-Real
        #:samples
        Positive-Integer
        #:style
        (or/c
         Integer
         'transparent
         'solid
         'bdiagonal-hatch
         'crossdiag-hatch
         'fdiagonal-hatch
         'cross-hatch
         'horizontal-hatch
         'vertical-hatch)
        #:z-max
        (or/c Real #f)
        #:z-min
        (or/c Real #f))
       any)
  contract from: 
      <pkgs>/plot-lib/plot/private/plot3d/surface.rkt
  blaming: /home/pedro/Desktop/graficos.rkt
   (assuming the contract is correct)
  at: <pkgs>/plot-lib/plot/private/plot3d/surface.rkt:49.9
```

It is absolutelly possible to graph this. I did it on Wolfram Alpha:

[image]

Comment: If you read the [documentation of surface3d](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/renderer3d.html?q=plot#%28part._3.D_.Surface_.Renderers%29) you can see that the functional parameter has two parameters, not three.

Comment: `f (x,y,z) = 2(x-2)^2 + (y-1)^2+(z-3)^2 - 10` is not an equation, it's a (definition of a) function of three parameters. The equation you're looking for is `2(x-2)^2 + (y-1)^2+(z-3)^2 = 10` (that is, `f(x,y,z) = 0`), which you entered into Wolfram. Solve it for one of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the details of the Racket implementation, what you are trying to do makes no sense.  You are trying to plot a function which maps from R^3 to R, and you can't do that as a surface plot in 3 dimensions: you need 4.

So, in as far as there is an answer to this problem, it is to rethink what you are trying to do.  One approach would be to curry your function so you can plot it for fixed values of one of its arguments: `(plot3d (surface3d (curryr (lambda (x y z) ...) 3.0) ...))` will plot it for z=3.0 for instance.

Comment: Actually, I tried that in Wolfram Alpha and it worked. I will update my post.

Comment: @fallowzito What alpha has done is plot the surface where that function is zero.  That is not the same thing as plotting the function at all.

Comment: you are absolutely right. And how do I do that? How do I plot this surface?